# jmx-term python subprocess poisons shell

Tags: java, python, jmx

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import *

p = Popen(
  args=("java","-jar","jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar"), 
  bufsize=0, 
  stdin=PIPE,
  stderr=PIPE
  )

p.stdin.write("open localhost:12345\n")
x = p.stderr.readline()
```

This needs a java process listening for a jmx client on port 12345.
The script "works": x is correct (when you print it or look at it in pdb).

**What's the problem then?** When this script terminates, the shell behaves strangely. On Linux and OS-X, typing in the shell isn't visible (although output is), and on windows, the first two characters typed per command are ignored. Executing the terminal "reset" command seems to fix it, but I don't want to inflict this on users of my script.

Removing the last line of the script (accessing p.stderr.readline()) eliminates the problem, but also the script's utility.

I've removed authentication to simplify the example. You'll note that I don't print x, to eliminate writing something nasty to the the shell as a culprit.

Versions: CPython 2.7 on Snow Leopard and various Linuxes; CPython 2.6.3 on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

jmxterm is probably doing some initialization for interactive use on the terminal and either because of a bug or because you don't close it explicitly it's not cleaning up after itself. The easiest way to avoid that is probably to connect its STDOUT to a PIPE, too, as you do for the other standard streams.

Answer (score 0):

jmxterm is doing things with your terminal. Simplest thing to do is to allow jmxterm to exit cleanly, thus cleaning itself up.

```
p.stdin.write('quit\n')
p.wait()
```